# writing a function to send a templated email using SMTP

Tags: python, email, smtp, jinja2, email-templates

I am trying to send a templated email using python, Jinja2, flask and SMTP. I have written the code for everything except actually sending the email using SMTP. Here is an abbreviated version of the code:

```
from email.message import EmailMessage
from flask import Flask
import smtplib
from jinja2 import Environment, PackageLoader, select_autoescape

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    send_template_email(
        template="email_template.html",
        to="recipient@email.com",
        subj="TEST",
        content="Hello"
    )

def send_template_email(template, to, subj, **kwargs):
    env = Environment(
        loader=PackageLoader("email_template", "templates"),
        autoescape=select_autoescape(["html", "xml"])
    )
    template = env.get_template("email_template.html")
    send_email(to, subj, template.render(**kwargs))

def send_email(to, subj, body):
```

for context, the simple html template looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title>email_template</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>{{content}}</p>
    </body>
```

The last thing i need to do is finish the `def send_email(to, subj, body):` function to make it send the email using SMTP. I am new to python and don't really know where to go from here. If someone could point me in the right direction or show me what an example of that function to actually send an email should look like I would GREATLY APPRECIATE IT. I believe that the email is generated, but the only thing that is left to do is to simply send it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the smtplib and email module ([doc here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.sendmail)) with the send_mail method.
Full example [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html#email-examples)

You first create a client at the same stage as your app (to avoid recreating one everytime):

```
from smtplib import SMTP
from email.message import EmailMessage
smtp_client = SMTP("domain.org")
```

then in your send_email first create a message from email.message :

```
msg['Subject'] = subj
msg['From'] = your_address
msg['To'] = to
msg.set_content(body)
```

then call

```
server.send_message(msg)
```